# Functions are not working in js prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed a jQuery plugin with prototypal inheritance.But functions are only working for main init() function and other prototypes are not working.

### My main function is

```
function Mynav(){
  ....
}

Mynav.prototype.linkBehaviour = function(){
     $('.nav-menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
         if ($(this).attr('href') !== '#') {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#preloader').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn').fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function() {
                 window.location = link;
            }, 1500)
         } else if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
              e.preventDefault();
         }
    });
}

Mynav.prototype.verticalConverter = function(){
     if (verticalNavOn) {

       if(!verticalLive){
          menuConverter();
          verticalLive = true;
        }

     }
     $(window).on('load resize', function(){
         width = $(window).width();
         if(width < 959){
            if(!verticalLive){
               menuConverter();   //This is a function also available with Mynav.prototype.menuConverter
               header.removeAttr('style');
               verticalLive = true;
            }
         } else{
             convertHorizontal();  // Its also a function available
             $('.header-fixed').attr('style',headerAttr);
              verticalLive = false;
         }
      });
}


function init(){
   new Mynav();
}

init();
```

In the upper codes `linkBehaviour` and `verticalconverter` is not working if i place `linkBehaviour` function in the main `Mynav()` it works then but not working in individual.
And i don't actually know about `load/resize` works with prototype or not .
Can any one help About the above two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Mynav(){

  this.verticalNavOn = false;

}

Mynav.prototype.linkBehaviour = function(){
     $('.nav-menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
         if ($(this).attr('href') !== '#') {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#preloader').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn').fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function() {
                 window.location = link;
            }, 1500)
         } else if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
              e.preventDefault();
         }
    });
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*   I believe that is in trouble when the RESIZE happens.
*
*   To make the BIND (on), you must pass the own plugin AHEAD. To be used in the event when it happens.
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Mynav.prototype.verticalConverter = function(){
    var self = this;

     if (self.verticalNavOn) {
       if(!self.verticalLive){
          self.menuConverter();
          self.verticalLive = true;
        }
     }

     // parse THIS plugin for EVENT
     $(window).on('load resize', {self: self}, function(e){

         // get SELF PLUGIN
         var self = e.data['self'];

         width = $(window).width();
         if(width < 959){
            if(!self.verticalLive){
               self.menuConverter();   //This is a function also available with Mynav.prototype.menuConverter
               header.removeAttr('style');
               self.verticalLive = true;
            }
         } else{
             self.convertHorizontal();  // Its also a function available
             $('.header-fixed').attr('style',headerAttr);
              self.verticalLive = false;
         }
      });
}


function init(){
   var x = new Mynav();

   // focing start function for tests
   x.verticalConverter();
}

init();
```

See full changes HTML and JS in: http://jsbin.com/ricaluredi/3

Comment: Well, you just change the code, correcting where there was error. I will redo the answer

Comment: Could you please explain me?

Comment: I believe that is in trouble when the RESIZE happens.

To make the BIND (on), you must pass the own plugin AHEAD. To be used in the event when it happens.

This must be done because when the event 'resize' happens, will be triggered by the WINDOW and how the function you want to call is within a plugin, you need INSTANCE initialized plugin.

I believe that with the above adjustments should be able to call your function

Comment: So when i resize there is `menuConverter is not defined` and `converthorizontal is not defined`

Comment: Thanks bro that's working. but `linkbehaviour` seems to be not working

Comment: Yes, I'm making some changes in the code to be correct.

Comment: Check HTML and JS in: [http://jsbin.com/ricaluredi/3](http://jsbin.com/ricaluredi/3)

Comment: Thanks.It seems that it works.But `activeCurrent` and `linkInViewport` is not working.But if i keep the codes inside this two function in the main js file they works.Any idea?

Comment: Next, if you are trying to call these two functions of other scripts simply calling for `activeCurrent()`, for example, you will not be able to execute them. Remember that the `new Overvilnavigation()` creates an Instance object, that is, if you need to call this function from other scripts, you must do so `('# menu').orvilnav().activeCurrent()`.